# Why can we drop an event in an intersection of events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I'm doing exercises from probability and the following comes up in a solution:

[Picture, click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eipU.png)

Why does $P(X \geqslant j+k, X \geqslant j)=P(X \geqslant j+k)$? If $j,k$ are nonnegative integers then knowing that $X \geqslant j+k$ we know for sure that $X \geqslant j$, but not *vice versa* since suppose $j = 2, k = 3$ so knowing $X \geqslant 2$ we don't know whether $X \geqslant 2+3=5$, so $X \geqslant j \subseteq X \geqslant j+k$. But the solution tells a reverse story. Why is that? Where is the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: The flaw is that you are misreading the statement you take issue with. It does not say that ($x\ge j+k$) is equivalent to ($x\ge j$). It says $(x\ge j+k$) is equivalent to $\big(x\ge j+k\;$ AND $\;x \ge j\big)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma is a shorthand for intersection, so the left-hand side is the probability of the event $\{X\geq j+k\}\cap \{X\geq j\}$. When one event is contained inside the other, the intersection of the two events is just the smaller event. Therefore $\{X\geq j+k\}\cap \{X\geq j\}=\{X\geq j+k\}$, hence the probabilities are equal.

Comment: I understand that, but I see the "smaller" event as $X \geqslant j$ and not $X \geqslant j+k$ (in which case there would be no question).

Comment: The smaller event is $X\geq j+k$. Try it with say $j=1$ and $k=2$: if $X\geq 3$ then certainly $X\geq 1$.

Comment: Ok, I think I had some kind of mental block, I think it's due to the fact that I was coding the whole day and now decided it would be good to do some maths. It's obvious now, thanks. I don't really know why I thought that the smaller one was $X \geqslant j$...